# Sobre o comportamento das funções de userland e funções internas no PHP

Tags: php, funções, php-8

Há uma proposta para unificar o comportamento de **userland** e **funções internas** no **PHP 8**. Que atualmente em particular, quando as funções internas não conseguem analisar os tipos de argumentos corretamente, elas falham retornando *null*. As funções de **Userland** lançam um *TypeError*.

Em relação qual seria o melhor comportamento, acredito que lançar um **TypeError**, seria o melhor comportamento.

Alguém poderia exemplificar. Uma explicação em código de tais comportamentos atualmente. Também se possível, sobre essa tal unificação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa proposta já foi aprovada e implementada e virá no PHP 8, de acordo com [essa rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/consistent_type_errors).

Com ela, argumentos inválidos passados para funções internas sempre resultarão num `TypeError` ao invés de um *warning* com retorno `null`.

Esse primeiro comportamento já acontece com algumas funções internas no PHP 7 caso seu código esteja usando `strict_types`, como é explicado num trecho da rfc:

```
var_dump(strlen(new stdClass));
// Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
// NULL

declare(strict_types=1);
var_dump(strlen(new stdClass));
// TypeError: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Comment: Obrigado. Li e achei esse ex. pelo link.
"Para funções definidas pelo usuário, passar um parâmetro de tipo ilegal resulta em um TypeError. Para funções internas, o comportamento depende de vários fatores, mas o padrão é lançar um aviso e retornar null. Este RFC propõe gerar consistentemente exceções TypeError para todos os tipos de parâmetros inválidos, independentemente de a função ser definida pelo usuário ou por extensão."
`function foo(int $bar) {}
foo("not an int"); 
// TypeError: Argument 1 passed to foo() must be of the type int, string given`